# React - Extremely simple Codepen will not show up

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I have a codepen. I need it to literally say "Hello world" with React. I can't get the code to render.

I have Babel set as the pre-compiler.

I have both React and ReactDOM linked.

Here is all of the HTML:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here is all of the JS:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I need to get this going for an interview in an hour or two. Just can't get it working here. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the content from the render function to display.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello!</p>
      </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return the component in `render`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```